# Django preload templates

Tags: django, templates, preload

It seems that Django (even with *DEBUG=False* and *TEMPLATE_DEBUG=False*) reloads HTML template files from local disk between requests. How do I make it preload all template files at application startup, and never attempt to reload them (unless I restart the server process)?

**Update:** I've found *django.template.loaders.cached.Loader* on http://www.jongales.com/blog/2012/02/16/make-django-keep-templates-in-memory/ . All I need now is to preload all templates at startup.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loader.get_template

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: When should I call it? Where in my project should I put the code which calls get_template in a loop?